# Cloudinary - add overlay text to thumbnailTransformation in image upload widget

Tags: cloudinary

I am using the upload image widget and I want to add a text overlay but don't know how, can someone answer me?

```
thumbnailTransformation: [{ width: 300, height: 300, crop: 'fill', border: "2px_solid_red" }],
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to include an `overlay` key that's an object with overlay parameters, in this case, text specific.

For example -

```
thumbnailTransformation: [
  {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    crop: 'fill',
    border: "2px_solid_red"
  },
  {
    overlay: {
      font_family: "Arial",
      font_size: 20,
      text: "Test"
    },
    gravity: "north_east"
  }
]
```

Below is a JSFiddle you can try: https://jsfiddle.net/rhdvgy19/

All the other available text styling options can be found here -
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#styling_parameters

Comment: I try to make the overlay to be in in north east, but it doesn't work.
`overlay: {
      font_family: "Arial",
      font_size: 20,
      text: "Test",
     gravity: "north_east"
    }
`
But it's always stay in the center.
I don't get your docs, it's not clear for the upload image widget.

Comment: Hi Aleksandar, can you tell me how to put it in the north east?

Comment: Hi @OffirPe'er. You can apply the "gravity" but it'll need to be outside of the "overlay" object. I.e. `overlay: { font_family: "Arial", font_size: 20, text: "Test"}, gravity: "north_east"`. I have edited my answer with a formatted version.

Comment: Hi Alexander, `thumbnailTransformation` doesn't work anymore, I opened a card in Cloudinary help center and also sent you a message in linkedin about it.
You can check it in your own fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rhdvgy19/

Comment: Hi Offir - I see that you raised the ticket directly with support and that it's being looked into.